# How to force reload a page to make POST request pass

Tags: laravel, vue.js

After checking if the user is able to join the presenceChannel, I expect data $user be shown on my page. It shows up after I hit refresh. My question is how to force reload the page without the need of uploading it manually(to make POST request pass)?

```
Broadcast::channel('online', function ($user) {
  if(auth()->check())
     return $user;
});
```

Component

```
<tbody>
       <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id"> 
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>
            <td>{{user.ip}}</td>
        </tr> 
</tbody>

export default { 
     data() {
        return {
            users:[],            
      }    
   },   

    mounted() {
           window.Echo.join('online')
            .here(users => (this.users = users))       
    }, 
}
```

Comment: It sounds from your comment like you are using `$user` directly in your page.  But `$user` is a PHP variable, which is server-side code — this means all PHP is processed before it ever leaves your server.  In order to update the page without refresh, you need to use client-side code, such as Vue/Javascript as it appears you are partially using.  But you haven't provided the part of your code that displays the variable on your page to give you any specific advice.

Comment: @matticustard  I've added code from <template> .This is where the user  shows up after I reload a page.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting your code.  It looks like we can rule out the PHP angle I mentioned in the comment above.  I think the problem is that you aren't listening for new users.

**# Joining Presence Channels**
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting#joining-presence-channels

> The **here** callback will be executed immediately once the channel is joined successfully, and will receive an array containing the user information for all of the other users currently subscribed to the channel.

To me, this indicates that the `here` method only fires once when your application joins the channel.  In order to receive new users, you will need to subscribe to additional events and push a new user to (or delete a user from) the users array as received.

```js
window.Echo.join('online')
    .here((users) => {
        // loads the initial data
        this.users = users;
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        // push a newly joining user to the users array
        // ...
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        // delete a user who is leaving from the users array
        // ...
    });
```

I didn't write any specific code for the additional methods since you may want to sort users in a particular way, but I think you should get the idea.